# Want to install AEM

Tags: aem

I am interested in AEM,so i wanna learn it but after searching everywhere I didn't get any setup for AEM.Please help me by sharing any learner setup or any link which can help me to Install "AEM 6.4 or more"

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Adobe for a temporary license or access to the product itself. Besides that, as Florian says, you can study the software stack that AEM uses, and see the GitHub projects (AEM Core Components, ACS Commons), etc, to see a few implementations, but in the end, you will need an instance to deploy code and actually see those components and Java bundles in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an instance of AEM for learning purposes. You could take training programs, or have a look at [Apache Sling](https://sling.apache.org). [Apache Sling](https://sling.apache.org) is the core component of AEM and you can learn the basic paradigms of AEM development starting with Sling.

Answer (score 0):

To install AEM, you need AEM jar and license file. Follow https://codingwithtea.blogspot.com/2021/08/aem-local-set-up.html to install AEM on local after getting aem jar and licence properties.